# Can I start a sentence with a singular noun with no article?

Tags: articles, indefinite-articles, definite-articles

For example, which one of the following sentences can I use?

> Consumer of Product X needs to fill out a rebate form […].
>   Consumers of Product X need to […].
>   A consumer of Product X needs to […].

This is for a general-purpose announcement.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Countable nouns need an article or similar, if singular:

> A consumer will fill out a rebate form.
>   Each consumer will fill out a rebate form.
>   The consumer will fill out a rebate form.
>   My dog ate my homework.

Generics/uncountable nouns need to be used without:

> Blood is running through the veins.
>   Water will be refilled at the next Oasis.

Answer (score 0):

The second one is the best choice. Or even better, ***All*** consumers of product X need to [...].