# Definite article in the beginning of a sentence

Tags: definite-articles, sentence-starts, uncountable-nouns

I'm confused with the usage of the definite article.

> During the development the following tasks were accomplished:
>
> - Software with a graphical interface was created;
> - [some other things]

I know exactly the software which was developed, and I am writing an annotation for my work.
Should I use *the* before *software*?

Comment: Difficult to say without more context. For example, are you contrasting software with graphical interface with software without graphical interface?

Comment: No,I am not contrasting anything. I have made a project and I'm describing it(it consists of several parts,software documentation,etc)

Comment: I haven't found an exact duplicate of your question, but the answers in some similar questions apply, and explain various rules; see e.g. [Can I start a sentence with a singular noun with no article?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11406/), [Do I need to use 'the' in this sentence?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/54630/), [When can I omit an indefinite article before a countable noun?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/49185/when-can-i-omit-an-indefinite-article-before-a-countable-noun)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple rule is:

If you had mentioned the particular piece of software in a previous sentence and this sentence is with reference to it, then begin with **The**.

If not, you are refering to 'some software' and so you will begin with **Software**.

Comment: Thanks,it is clear now. It was not mentioned before. I introduce the things i made in my annotation.

Answer (score 3):

*The* before *software* is unnecessary (and I think awkward); *the* before *development* is unnecessary and awkward; the article *a* should be added before *graphical*.  Thus:

> During  development the following tasks were accomplished:
>    • Software with a graphical interface was created.

or

> During  development the following tasks were accomplished:
>    • Software with graphic interface was created.

Comment: Thank you. I agree it is awkward. But how can we omit an article if we are talking about an exact object(not one from some generality) and it is not a name or something else like that? Is there any precise rule in English grammar?

Comment: "During the development" indicates a software application was (being) developed!  So, watchout, the article **The** is not superfluous.

Comment: @Kris, are you suggesting that "During the development" indicates an app was developed, but that "During development" does not?  Pray explain why.

Comment: Not at all. "During the development" shows that an application software was mentioned earlier, the development of which we are now speaking of. So, if the next sentence is probably about that same piece of s/w, in which case, the article is required.

Comment: @Kris, I feel obliged to disagree.  See, for example, book refs for *[during development](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22during%20development%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en)* and *[during the development](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22during%20the%20development%22&tbs=bks:1&lr=lang_en)*.  You will observe in the former set usage as in my answer (*development* as a noun), and in the latter set, with *development* as an adjective; eg "during the development of gait".

Comment: Once again, I am not referring to the article with 'development', but the one before 'software'.  Pl re-read my comment.

Comment: I agree with this answer, save for one exception: "_Software with graphic interface was created_" sounds awkward to me.

Comment: @J.R. - Forms like that are common in "[telegraphic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telegraphic_speech)" reports, for example in brief weekly status reports.

Comment: Ah! Yes, I see it now.  I should have pictured it on a PowerPoint slide.  _Mea culpa_.

Comment: However, I should have cast that example into an active form: *eg*  "Created software with graphic interface"